# rails: count and group with joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have the following models:

```
Car: 
has_many :car_classes  

CarClass:
belongs_to :Car
belongs_to :CarMainClass

CarMainClass:
has_many :car_classes
```

What I want to do is to count the amount of cars in CarClass grouped by the car_main_class_id but then linked to the main_class_symbol which is in CarMainClass.

The query I have now is:

```
CarClass.group(:car_main_class_id).count(:car_id) => {43=>79, 45=>4 ...}
```

Which is almost what I want, except that I end up only with the :car_main_class_id which I to be the :main_class_symbol from CarMainClass:

```
{"A1"=>79, "A2"=>4 ...}
```

I tried joining the tables and custom select options, but they didn't work.

Can this be done in a query in which I don't have to iterate through the main classes again?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your model names are not good. Could CarMainClass be better named as CarCompany (or something similar)?

Comment: Hey Tom, I know haha thanks for the advice. I actually renamed them in this question to make them a bit more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a SQL approach and using a "count/group by", you should look to a very simple feature of Rails ActiveRecords : the **counter_cache** column.

For example, you can add a column "car_classes_count" in the CarMainClass, and in CarClass class, you do like this :

```
CarClass:
belongs_to :car
belongs_to :car_main_class, :counter_cache => true
```

You can do the same with a column "car_class_count" in Car.

I don't know if it can help, but I had the same kind of problems when I started to develop with Rails. I tried to do some unsuccessful crazy SQL queries (queries that worked w/ sqlite, but did not w/ postgres) and I finally choose an other approach.

Comment: Thanks man. I have indeed just started with rails, I didn't know I could use it for this purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CarClass.includes(:car_main_class => :car_classes)
 .group(:car_main_class_id).map { |cc| 
   { cc.car_main_class.main_class_symbol => cc.car_main_class.cars.size }
 }
```

Although this is quite ugly - I agree with @Tom that you should try to think of more meaningful class names.

Comment: Thanks Thilo! this will work! I realize now that there is no query possible in which you don't loop through the results. Counter cashing seems a good answer.